# Unknown Constants AssetsController::S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm attempting to download files from my S3 File server via a rails app that I've written.  However, I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how to accomplish this.  I've been attempting to use [this reference](https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx354Y6VTZ421PJ/Downloading-Objects-from-Amazon-S3-using-the-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby) from Amazon's blog to get it working.

in the get method in my controller, I have the following:

```
asset = current_user.assets.find_by_id(params[:id])
File.open('filename', 'wb') do |file|
  reap = s3.get_object({ bucket:'bucket-name', key: URI.encode(asset.uploaded_file.url)}, target: file)
end
```

however I'm getting the following error:

> uninitialized constant AssetsController::s3

I'm using the gem aws-sdk.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> uninitialized constant AssetsController::s3

You need to define `s3`, the below should work

```
asset = current_user.assets.find_by_id(params[:id])
File.open('filename', 'wb') do |file|
  s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new
  reap = s3.get_object({ bucket:'bucket-name', key: URI.encode(asset.uploaded_file.url)}, target: file)
end
```